# How dump assembler from executable

Tags: c#, assembly

I have an executable I compiled with C# and I would like to dump the code in assembler code from it, are there any tools to do that?
Also is it possible to also create an executable from the assembler generated?

Comment: Use ildasm.exe to look at the generated IL.  And yes, ilasm.exe can reconstruct the .exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't compile down to assembler level, it compiles into a common intermediate language (CIL), which isn't the same thing. Compiled C# requires an interpreter, and always will. You can't just copy pieces of the compiled form into a non .NET program.

Comment: "Compiled C# requires an interpreter" - Technically, no. CIL requires a VM (and even that isn't a universal law, there are niche CPUs that execute JVM bytecode and the same should be possible for CIL), but compiling C# to something other than CIL (e.g. native code) is possible. It would likely still require *some* runtime (e.g. for GC; this could be statically linked into the executable). It's just a huge project and provides close to zero adcantages over using CIL and leveraging existing implementations and their JIT compilers (or `ngen` if AOT-compilation is required).

Comment: Startup time is the most important native advantage. Afaik NGEN was developed to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't compile to machine code, or at least the Microsoft C# compiler doesn't compile to machine code.  However, you can get the intermediate language bytecode in an assembly-like printout using [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Also, if you want to see one way that the CLR could just-in-time compile your C# code, compile to assembly language using Mono.  An example given on their [website](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT):

```
mono --aot program.exe
```

Then you can objdump -d to get assembly language from this, at least on a *nix/Mac machine, or a Windows machine with Cygwin or MinGW.